# Percentile in Case Statement In Athena SQL

Tags: sql, case, window-functions, amazon-athena

Trying to execute this in Athena SQL. I have '75' as default tax_type which i need to replace with '76' for 20% of tax_amt

Current output as is

```
geocode  tax_type  tax_amt
32         75       10
32         75       15
32         75       20
32         75       18
32         75       20
32         75       17
```

I need output as

```
geocode  tax_type  tax_amt
32         75       10
32         75       15
32         75       20
32         75       18
32         76       20
32         75       17
```

I keep getting below error:

> "GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations or window functions:
> ["count"("tax_amt"), "count"(*), "count"("tax_amt"), "count"(*)]"

If i remove from `group by` clause then it says

> "must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause"

Any help would be really appreciated

SQL

```
   WITH a AS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_fact" 
    WHERE dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) 
                FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_fact")
   )
, b AS 
    (SELECT g.geocode_id
         , g.geocode
         , coalesce(sq_actual_names.actual_name, g.jurisdiction_name) AS JUR_NAME
    FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim" g 
    LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT REPLACE(geocode,'-','') AS stripped_geocode
               , MAX(jurisdiction_name) AS actual_name
        FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim" 
        WHERE 1=1 AND dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) 
                            FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim")
        AND (geocode = geocode OR geocode = SUBSTRING(geocode,1,2) || '-' || 
                                            SUBSTRING(geocode,3,3) || '-' || 
                                            SUBSTRING(geocode,6,4))
        AND jurisdiction_name <> 'U'
        GROUP BY 1) sq_actual_names
     ON g.geocode = sq_actual_names.stripped_geocode
     WHERE 1=1 
       AND g.dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim")
       AND (geocode = geocode OR geocode = SUBSTRING(geocode,1,2) || '-' || 
                                           SUBSTRING(geocode,3,3) || '-' || 
                                           SUBSTRING(geocode,6,4))
   )
, d AS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_code_dim" 
     WHERE dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) 
                 FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_code_dim")
    )   
, agg AS
    (SELECT 
          CASE 
               WHEN d.tax_auth = '1' THEN SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) || '0000000' 
               WHEN d.tax_auth = '2' THEN SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,5) || '0000' 
               ELSE b.geocode 
          END AS GEOCODE
         , b.JUR_NAME AS JURIS_NAME
         , CAST(COUNT(a.tax_amt)/COUNT(*)*100 AS DECIMAL(30,2)) AS PERCENTILE
         , d.tax_type 
         , CAST (d.tax_rate AS DECIMAL (30,5)) AS TAX_RATE
         , SUM(CAST(a.tax_amt AS DECIMAL(30,2))) AS TAX
         , SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) AS STATE_GEO
         , 'PPD Boost Usage' AS ID
         , d.tax_auth AS TAX_AUTH
         , f.auth_name AS AUTH_NAME
         , CASE 
              WHEN SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) = '72'
              THEN '417' 
              ELSE '317' 
          END AS BU
        , c.tax_descrp AS TAX_DESCRP
        , CASE 
              WHEN b.geocode LIKE '%-%-%' 
              THEN b.geocode 
              ELSE SUBSTRING(geocode,1,2) || '-' || 
                   SUBSTRING(geocode,3,3) || '-' || 
                   SUBSTRING(geocode,6,4) 
          END AS GEOMASK 
        , 'NO' AS COST_RECOVERY_IDENTIFIER
        , CONCAT(SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2),d.tax_auth,d.tax_type) AS GL_CROSS_REF
        , SUBSTRING(load_id,1,6) AS YYYYMM
        , c.gl_account AS GL_ACCOUNT
        , d.tax_srv_type

    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b
      ON a.geocode_id = b.geocode_id

    LEFT JOIN  d    
      ON a.tax_code_id = d.tax_code_id

    LEFT JOIN "sbx_accntnganalytics"."tax_auth_name" f
       ON d.tax_auth = f.tax_auth

    LEFT JOIN "sbx_accntnganalytics"."tax_gl_desc" c
       ON d.tax_type = c.tax_type 
       AND SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) = c.state_geo

    GROUP BY 1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
)
SELECT GEOCODE
       , JURIS_NAME
       , PERCENTILE
       , CASE 
                when STATE_GEO = '32' AND tax_type = '75' AND CAST(COUNT(tax)/COUNT(*)*100 AS DECIMAL(30,2)) = 0.20 
                THEN REPLACE (tax_type,'75','76') else tax_type end as tax_type
       , TAX_RATE
       , TAX
       , STATE_GEO
       , TAX_AUTH
       , AUTH_NAME
       , BU
       , TAX_DESCRP
       , GEOMASK 
       , COST_RECOVERY_IDENTIFIER
       , GL_CROSS_REF
       , YYYYMM
       , GL_ACCOUNT
       , tax_srv_type
FROM agg
```

Comment: Getting below error @Parfait:SYNTAX_ERROR: line 5:1: GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations or window functions: ["count"("a"."tax_amt"), "count"(*), "count"("a"."tax_amt"), "count"(*)]

Comment: @Parfait: i have edited my SQL in the main text box.Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that you want:

```
select geocode, tax_type, 
    case when ntile(5) over(order by id) = 1 then 76 else tax_amt end tax_amt
from mytable
```

This assumes that column `id` can be used to *sort* the records. The query identifies the top 20% records with window function `ntil()`, and assigns value `76` to column `tax_amt`.

Comment: @Harry: no. `ntile()` distributes the rows in 5 groups of even size, no matter the number of rows.

Comment: @Harry: obviously this is very different than the query I gave you. An obviously as well, comments are not meant to provide such large code blocks. I can't suggest here.

Comment: i have edited my SQL in the main text box.Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because your are combining a grouping column with aggregate in same expression, you run into the `GROUP BY` error. Consider aggregating first then run your `CASE` expression which can be facilitated with common table expressions (CTE) using [`WITH`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html#select-parameters) clause. You can even flatten your `CASE` with multiple `WHEN` logical expression.

```sql
WITH a AS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_fact" 
    WHERE dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) 
                FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_fact")
   )
, b AS 
    (SELECT g.geocode_id
         , g.geocode
         , coalesce(sq_actual_names.actual_name, g.jurisdiction_name) AS JUR_NAME
    FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim" g `enter code here`
    LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT REPLACE(geocode,'-','') AS stripped_geocode
               , MAX(jurisdiction_name) AS actual_name
        FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim" 
        WHERE 1=1 AND dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) 
                            FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim")
        AND (geocode = geocode OR geocode = SUBSTRING(geocode,1,2) || '-' || 
                                            SUBSTRING(geocode,3,3) || '-' || 
                                            SUBSTRING(geocode,6,4))
        AND jurisdiction_name <> 'U'
        GROUP BY 1) sq_actual_names
     ON g.geocode = sq_actual_names.stripped_geocode
     WHERE 1=1 
       AND g.dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_geocode_dim")
       AND (geocode = geocode OR geocode = SUBSTRING(geocode,1,2) || '-' || 
                                           SUBSTRING(geocode,3,3) || '-' || 
                                           SUBSTRING(geocode,6,4))
   )
, d AS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_code_dim" 
     WHERE dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) 
                 FROM "dl_wireless_boost"."ngpp_tax_code_dim")
    )   
, agg AS
    (SELECT 
          CASE 
               WHEN d.tax_auth = '1' THEN SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) || '0000000' 
               WHEN d.tax_auth = '2' THEN SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,5) || '0000' 
               ELSE b.geocode 
          END AS GEOCODE
         , b.JUR_NAME AS JURIS_NAME
         , CAST(COUNT(a.tax_amt)/COUNT(*)*100 AS DECIMAL(30,2)) AS PERCENTILE,
         , d.tax_type
         , CAST (d.tax_rate AS DECIMAL (30,5)) AS TAX_RATE
         , SUM(CAST(a.tax_amt AS DECIMAL(30,2))) AS TAX
         , SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) AS STATE_GEO
         , 'PPD Boost Usage' AS ID
         , d.tax_auth AS TAX_AUTH
         , f.auth_name AS AUTH_NAME
         , CASE 
              WHEN SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) = '72'
              THEN '417' 
              ELSE '317' 
          END AS BU
        , c.tax_descrp AS TAX_DESCRP
        , CASE 
              WHEN b.geocode LIKE '%-%-%' 
              THEN b.geocode 
              ELSE SUBSTRING(geocode,1,2) || '-' || 
                   SUBSTRING(geocode,3,3) || '-' || 
                   SUBSTRING(geocode,6,4) 
          END AS GEOMASK 
        , 'NO' AS COST_RECOVERY_IDENTIFIER
        , CONCAT(SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2),d.tax_auth,d.tax_type) AS GL_CROSS_REF
        , SUBSTRING(load_id,1,6) AS YYYYMM
        , c.gl_account AS GL_ACCOUNT
        , d.tax_srv_type

    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b
      ON a.geocode_id = b.geocode_id

    LEFT JOIN  d    
      ON a.tax_code_id = d.tax_code_id

    LEFT JOIN "sbx_accntnganalytics"."tax_auth_name" f
       ON d.tax_auth = f.tax_auth

    LEFT JOIN "sbx_accntnganalytics"."tax_gl_desc" c
       ON d.tax_type = c.tax_type 
       AND SUBSTRING(b.geocode,1,2) = c.state_geo

    GROUP BY 1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
)

SELECT GEOCODE
       , JURIS_NAME
       , PERCENTILE
       , CASE 
                WHEN STATE_GEO = '32' AND d.tax_type = '75' AND PERCENTILE = 0.20 
                THEN REPLACE (d.tax_type,'75','76') 
                WHEN (STATE_GEO <> '32' OR d.tax_type <> '75') AND PERCENTILE = 0.80 
                THEN d.tax_type 
                ELSE NULL
         END AS TAX_TYPE
       , TAX_RATE
       , TAX
       , STATE_GEO
       , ID
       , TAX_AUTH
       , AUTH_NAME
       , BU
       , TAX_DESCRP
       , GEOMASK 
       , COST_RECOVERY_IDENTIFIER
       , GL_CROSS_REF
       , YYYYMM
       , GL_ACCOUNT
       , tax_srv_type
FROM agg
```

Aside - be sure to heed [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) with more informative aliases.

Comment: Hello @Parfait, i tried using your solution but am still getting the same issue. Please see modified code in main text box: